# I want to generate n! permutations for a given n in R

Tags: r, permutation

suppose n=3
then output should be: a vector containing vectors: 
123
213
132
231
321

Answer (score 6):

This will solve your question:

```
install.packages("combinat")
require(combinat)
permn(1:3)
```

Also the functions:  choose, combn ,expand.grid
Might prove useful for you in the future.

Answer (score 6):

```
library(gtools)
permutations(3,3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    3    2
[3,]    2    1    3
[4,]    2    3    1
[5,]    3    1    2
[6,]    3    2    1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `gregmisc` package should have the `permutations()` function.

```
permutations3,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some non-recursive code for this:

```
maxdepth <- 4
curdepth <- 1
l <- list()
i <- 0
while (i < maxdepth) {
    l <- c(l, 1)
    i <- i+1
}
done <- 0
results <- list()
resct <- 1

print(paste(sep=",",l))

while (curdepth > 0) {
    if (curdepth == maxdepth) {
        results[[resct]] <- l
        resct <- resct+1
        l[[curdepth]] <- l[[curdepth]]+1
    }
    if (l[[curdepth]] == maxdepth+1) {
        while (!done && l[[curdepth]] == maxdepth+1) {
            l[[curdepth]] <- 1
            curdepth <- curdepth-1
            if (curdepth == 0) {
                done <- 1
            }
        }
        if (!done) {
            l[[curdepth]] <- l[[curdepth]]+1
        }
    } else if (curdepth < maxdepth) {
        curdepth <- curdepth+1
    }
}
```

edit: made to output vector instead of printing; when done, "results" should contain the desired answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the case, but I'll give it a try.
If you'd like to do something with huge number of permutations of a bit longer vectors, it is much less demanding and about as good to use Monte Carlo and simply sample the space with large number of random permutations (that might be generated in R with `sample` function).

Answer (score 0):

A while back I had to do this in base R without loading any packages:

```
permutations <- function(n){
    if(n==1){
        return(matrix(1))
    } else {
        sp <- permutations(n-1)
        p <- nrow(sp)
        A <- matrix(nrow=n*p,ncol=n)
        for(i in 1:n){
            A[(i-1)*p+1:p,] <- cbind(i,sp+(sp>=i))
        }
        return(A)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
> permutations(3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    3    2
[3,]    2    1    3
[4,]    2    3    1
[5,]    3    1    2
[6,]    3    2    1
```